# IDE installed on Android device?

Tags: android, ide

I have a Note 9 and I'm using the DEX feature.  I'm looking for a good IDE that I can use to develop native android apps.  I recently tried out AIDE from the play store, and that will fulfill most basic needs, but I'd like to have something closer to Eclipse or Android Studio that I can use when I'm using the Samsung DEX feature.

Keep in mind that this is NOT something that I 'need'.  I have an actual development desktop in my office.  And I can remote to that machine for my more intensive development needs.  But DEX is extremely convenient for travel or even when I just want to work in my living room.

Thanks.